# setting text of TextView , using custom listView Adaptor

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter, listview-adapter

I am trying to use custom list View adapter, to customize UI of the listView. But I am not able to setTextview of the custom List View. `titleView.setText(tem);` in custom Adapter is not working. It is not giving any error. It displays empty string in Text View (Which I set from Adapter class dynamically), and display text View correctly, which is hard coded in the itemlistView (shows that the custom adapter is correctly connected with the fragment). Could someone help me with this ?

Fragment class displaying list

```
public class Help_FromFriend_OfferedFragment extends Fragment {

    ListView msgList;
    ArrayList<post> details;
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;
    private String Preference;

    public Help_FromFriend_OfferedFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_help__from_friend__offered, container, false);

        msgList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView_post);

        details = new ArrayList<post>();

        post Detail;
        Detail = new post();
        Detail.setPost_heading("Heading 1");
        Detail.setPost_owner_name("Bob");
        details.add(Detail);

        Detail = new post();
        Detail.setPost_heading("Heading 2");
        Detail.setPost_owner_name("Bob 2");
        details.add(Detail);

        msgList.setAdapter(new postListViewCustomAdaptor(details, getActivity()));

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Fragment layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"


tools:context="com.example.Help_FromFriend_OfferedFragment"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_help__from_friend__offered"
android:background="#999999"
>

<ListView
    android:background="#984442"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView_post"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top" />

</FrameLayout>
```

custom Adaptor class

```
public class postListViewCustomAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<post> _data;
    Context _c;

    postListViewCustomAdaptor (ArrayList<post> data, Context c){
        _data = data;
        _c = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return _data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return _data.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)_c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_post, null);
            Log.v("custom Adaptor","v is null   ");
        }


        //ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.post_photo);
        TextView titleView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
        TextView ownerNameView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.post_owner_name);


        post post_details = _data.get(position);
        //image.setImageResource(post_details .getPost_photo());
        Log.v("custom Adaptor", "setting postHeading: " + post_details.getPost_heading());
        String tem ="faltu";

        Log.v("custom Adaptor", "title from View : " +  titleView.getText());

        titleView.setText(tem);
        ownerNameView.setText(post_details .getPost_owner_name());
        return v;
    }
}
```

list_item_post.xml (custom list item)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" >
     
            <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/post_photo"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="40dp" />
      
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="oo"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#896322" /> 

            <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/post_title"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="ahaha"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#003366" /> 

         <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/post_owner_name"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#003366" /> 
     
         
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the layout params on the `TextView`s within your `LinearLayout`. They are all `match_parent` width, meaning the first is squashing the second and third to nothing.

Use `layout_width="0dp"` and `layout_weight="1"` to give all of the `TextView`s equal width.